# New SQL Connection Not Appearing in LocalHost

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, localhost, wamp

I'm trying to make a new connection to mysqladmin, but for reason's I cannot figure out, it will not work.
From what I can see I have everything correct. Can someone please take a look and see what I am doing wrong?

Firstly, the User:
[PHPmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWiwb.png)

and then my sql:
[my sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxHA7.png)

finally the localhost, the file is saved in a folder in the www folder of wamp so I have no idea why it is not showing. It is just blank.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank u very much in advance.

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code rather than linking an image. You should also clearly define the problem and include details of error messages.

Comment: sorry, i thought images would be clearer. there is no error message. There is no file when i open the localhost in the browser, the index is blank, thats my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling your php script what to do if the MySQL connection is successful, thats why output is blank.

Also, i suggest you using mysqli object

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'Desino', 'password');

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Cannot connect: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I just added the echo, but its the same... when i go onto the browser and go to local host, and click the file where the .php page is saved, the index is blank

Comment: Are you sure that your php file is not generating a 500 server error? Can you enable error reporting and display errors directives? Also, take a look at your debug console -> network, it should say whether the response status is 200 OK or 500 internal server error (if so, you have a php error in your file)